# Need help using datalist input to generate a form

Tags: javascript, forms, variables

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I've been digging for a few hours now with little luck.

What I'm trying to accomplish: I wish to have a form that starts by asking the user how many children they need to register (minimum of 1 max of 10).  I then need to be able to use this variable to make visible up to 10 entry fields for the children. What I was planning on doing is using the value from the datalist then using an if/else statement to generate the form. (if id = 2 then (form looks like this...) else...  What I don't know how to do is capture the choice and then pass it to the if/then statement.

```
<h2>How many children are you registering?</h2>
    <input type="range" value="1" "min=1" max="10" list="number" />
<datalist id="number">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  </datalist>
```

Comment: try a search for it on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery

Try with this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>How many children are you registering?</h2>


<input type="range" value="1" "min=1" max="10" list="number" id="list" />
<datalist id="number">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</datalist>
<div id="form_input">

</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#list').change(function(){
    var i = $(this).val();
    var m = 0;
    $('#form_input').html("");
    if(i != 0){
        $('#form_input').append('<form id="form">');    
        while(m<i){
            $('#form_input').append('<input type="text" id="text_'+m+'" name="text_'+m+'" />');           m++;
        }
        $('#form_input').append('</form>'); 
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a ton.  Would vote, but don't have enough rep yet ;-/

Comment: don't worry, the important is this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<h2>How many children are you registering?</h2>
    <input type="range" value="1" "min=1" max="10" list="number" onChange="change(this);" />
<datalist id="number">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  </datalist>
<div id="childrens">
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT (in < head >):

```
function change(el) {
    var container = document.getElementById('childrens'),
        child;
    // Clear container
    container.innerHTML = '';
    // Add number of child inputs
    for (var i=0; i<el.value; i++) {
        child = document.createElement("input");
        child.type = 'text';
        container.appendChild( child );
    }
}
```

[Click here for JSFIDLE demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V2J8J/)